# Как расставить операторы чтобы получилось максимальное число?

Tags: python, python-3.x, комбинаторика

Идея усложнить задачу. Первоначальное условие: вводятся три числа: a, b, c. Нужно расставить операторы (+ / * и скобки - ** не используем) так, чтобы получилось максимальное число. То есть, банально выбрать максимум из нескольких комбинаций: a + b * c; a * (b + c); a * b * c; (a + b) * c; a + b + c а также a * b + c.

Что если сделать условие этой зада более универсальным? То есть, для разного количества введенных чисел. А также, автоматически перебирать все комбинации операторов. Ведь даже для трех чисел пришлось несколько раз перепроверять все ли возможные варианты задействованы. Решение вышло также, мягко говоря, не очень изящным. Для четырех-пяти это будет еще более-менее посильно сделать вручную, но дальше начинается темный лес.
Возможно ли решить задачу в новой формулировке?
Как это сделать:

- максимально кратко
- максимально понятно (даже для новичка, забегающего немного вперед в учебе).

Comment: мне кажется, автор довольно мало рассказал о себе, о погоде и предпочтениях в музыке.

Comment: Формула - двоичное дерево. В листьях числа, в узлах - операции. Переберите все такие деревья. Перечисление деревьев - известная задача.

Comment: Переберите все корректные (и не корректные тоже) выражения в [обратной польской нотации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). На Питоне можно уложиться в двадцать строчек: пятнадцать строчек - калькулятор, пять строчек - перебор.

Comment: Решите задачу по индукции. Если вы умеет вычислять максимум для `k` чисел, как это сделать для `k + 1` числа? Перебрать все пары чисел (a, b) и все операции (@), сосчитать a @ b, вызвать расчёт для меньшего числа чисел. Кажется это самый короткий способ.

Comment: Да, операторы. Спасибо за поправку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как расставить знаки операций и скобки всеми возможными способами? Если число одно, то оно и результат. Если чисел больше, то разбиваем список чисел всеми возможными способами на две части. Для обеих частей рекурсивно находим значения, пробуем их сложить и умножить. Это всё.

Ниже код, в котором главное - простота. Он сносно работает для десяти чисел. Если нужно больше, поиск можно оптимизировать, и довольно существенно.

```
def values(args, i1, i2):
    if i1 + 1 == i2:
        yield args[i1]
    for i in range(i1 + 1, i2):
        for lhs in values(args, i1, i):
            for rhs in values(args, i, i2):
                yield lhs + rhs
                yield lhs * rhs

def main():
    args = [float(w) for w in input().split()]
    print(max(values(args, 0, len(args))))


main()
```

> ```
> $ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | python max-expr.py
> 5443200.0
>
> $ echo -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 | python max-expr.py
> 3628800.0
> ```